# How to install nautilus-actions-extra in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nautilus

I would like to install nautilus-actions-extra in my ubuntu 16.04. I try step by step as below:
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nae-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions nautilus-actions-extra

but when I try last step install nautilus-actions-extra. it doesn't work. Output say "Unable to locate package nautilus-actions-extra"

Pls let me know how to solve and is there any other package like nautilus.

Comment: You got the `Unable to locate package nautilus-actions-extra` error message because ppa:nae-team/ppa does not have any packages in it for Ubuntu 16.04